# Trying to present SwiftUI from HostingViewController with Enviroment Variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to present some SwiftUI from UI Kit with the following code:

```
class SavedListViewController: UIHostingController<SavedEventListView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {

        let listView = SavedEventListView().environmentObject(RemindersViewModel())
        super.init(rootView: listView) // BUILD ERROR HERE = "Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'SavedEventListView'"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

When I do this, I get `Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'SavedEventListView'`

If I try force casting `listView` as! `SavedEventListView`, the app crashes.

If I don't provide an environment variable, the app crashes when as well.

> Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<_.SavedEventListView, SwiftUI.EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier.RemindersViewModel>>>' (0x7fff89e46b90) to '_.SavedEventListView' (0x10a2447d0).

Any suggestions on how to fix this and get this swiftui view to present?
Thanks

Other code

```
class RemindersViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var savedEvents = RemindersStore().fetchRuns()
}

struct SavedEventListView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var reminders: RemindersViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(reminders.savedEvents) { reminder in
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("$\(reminder.title)")
                                    .font(.headline)

                                Text("$\(reminder.category)")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.light)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Text("$\(reminder.date)")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "calendar.badge.minus")!)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Reminders")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the simplest variant I would use:

```
class SavedListViewController: UIHostingController<AnyView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {

        let listView = SavedEventListView().environmentObject(RemindersViewModel())
        super.init(rootView: AnyView(listView))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**Update (Xcode 13.3)** now it seems I have better idea for that, at least strict type:

```
class SavedListViewController: UIHostingController<SavedListViewController.MyView> {

    struct MyView: View {
        var body: some View {
            SavedEventListView().environmentObject(RemindersViewModel())
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(rootView: MyView())
    }

// ...
}
```

Comment: In your first example, is it not bad practice using `AnyView`?

Comment: As I wrote see updated section... that was first answer with AnyView, just kept it to show possibility... actually until something is present in public API it can be used, all depends on where/how/why... and if developer knows all cons&pros. Sometimes it's just the only case... Apple uses it as well... the longer you debug the more interesting you see in stack :)

Answer (score 2):

At the time I was going to post an answer, it was already posted by @Asperi. I would like to add some context to that answer.

As per your code, you seem to use the super initializer of `public init(rootView: Content)` instead of `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder, rootView: Content)`. If you don't use the latter, anything added to the `SavedListViewController` in the **Interface Builder** won't be available. So you need to use that said super call:

```
class SavedListViewController: UIHostingController<AnyView> {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        let listView = SavedEventListView().environmentObject(RemindersViewModel())
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: AnyView(listView))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Comment: Is using AnyView not considered bad practice? Also I'm curious how they code would work if the view model is injected. If in the view controller I have `init(viewModel: RemindersViewModel)` and then `let view = AnnotateImageToolbar().environmentObject(state)` `super.init(rootView: view)` I get the error Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'AnyView'